# bluetooth gatt server : how to set the appearance characteristic?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-things, bluetooth-gatt

I've created a Bluetooth Gatt server on Android : I was able to implement/configure a new service (thanks to the https://github.com/androidthings/sample-bluetooth-le-gattserver), but unfortunately, I am not able to change the "appearance" of the service.

From my understanding, I need to modify the Appearance characteric of the Generic Access Profile (https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/generic-access-profile), but I'm stuck as it does not exit, and if try to create it, it fails with a  status=133 error. (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/android-5.1.1_r13/stack/include/gatt_api.h)

```
final UUID SERVICE_GENERIC_ACCESS = UUID.fromString("00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
final UUID CHARACTERISTIC_APPEARANCE = UUID.fromString("00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

BluetoothManager mBluetoothGattServer = mBluetoothManager.openGattServer(this, mGattServerCallback);
BluetoothGattService genericService =  mBluetoothGattServer.getService(SERVICE_GENERIC_ACCESS);
BluetoothGattService genericService = new BluetoothGattService(
            SERVICE_GENERIC_ACCESS,
            BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);
BluetoothGattCharacteristic icon = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(CHARACTERISTIC_APPEARANCE, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ);
mBluetoothGattServer.addService(genericService);

public void onServiceAdded(int status, BluetoothGattService service) {
// Fails with error 133
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Cheers

D